# sending sigint between processes running on separate consoles Windows 7 and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, signals, kill, sigint

I have inherited a test executive that launches test scripts in their own instance of Python, in their own console. The instance of python communicates with the test executive via tcp/ip connection. Currently, if the user stops the script via the test executive, the test executive does a taskkill on the pid of the python instance running the script. This prevents running any clean up function that would normally execute if the script execution completes on its own. I'm trying to rectify this by sending a SIGINT or some other signal to the python instance via the pid of said instance. Then in my test scripts it will have a handle function that will raise the KeyboardInterrupt execption which the scripts will be coded to catch and then execute the clean up function. I tried testing this out using python 3. I have 2 scripts that I run from separate python instances/consoles to best simulate how it would work. One script, os_stop.py, defines the handler function to raise the KeyboardInterrupt if the SIGINT signal is received. This script also prints its pid and runs a a loop displaying an output messages every 5 seconds just to simulate the running of a test script. The other script, send_stop.py, sends the SIGINT to the pid of the first script (note: the pid is passed as a parameter to the script). When executed, send_stop.py does cause os_stop.py to stop, but it doesn't raise the interrupt. I'm guessing a kill is just being executed and the SIGINT is not just being received by the first script. Below is the script code. Any help would be greatly apprecited:

'''

```
os_stop.py
---------
import os
import time
import signal

print("pid - {}".format(os.getpid()))

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("CAUGHT SIGNAL!!!!")
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

FIVE_SECS = 5
elapsed = 5
start_time = time.time()
try:
    while True:
        if elapsed >= FIVE_SECS:
            print("Waiting ...")
            elapsed = 0
            start_time = time.time()
        else:
            elapsed = time.time() - start_time
        time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped by user")
except signal.SIGINT:
    print("HERE")
```

'''

'''

```
send_stop.py
------------

import os
import sys
import signal

def send_sigint(pid):
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
    
send_sigint(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

'''

Comment: `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)` will just open the process via `OpenProcess` and call `TerminateProcess`, which is like Unix `SIGKILL`. Two 'signals' (the NT kernel does not implement POSIX signals) are special cased for Windows console apps: `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` (0) and `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (1), in which case it calls WinAPI `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(ctrlEvent, processGroupId)`. But these 'signal' values should only be used if the process identified as `pid` is attached to the same console as the caller and was created with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

Comment: This hybrid behavior should have been split into separate `os.kill` (call `OpenProcess`, `TerminateProcess`) and `os.killpg` (call `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`) calls. Or at least reserve the process-group behavior for negative PID values. But we're stuck with the current mess.

Comment: Use ctypes to open a handle to the process via `OpenProcess`. Spawn a child process as a `DETACHED_PROCESS` and pass it the PID of the target process. Have it use ctypes to call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, True)` (ignore Ctrl+C),  `AttachConsole(pid)`, and `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)`, and then exit. This sends to group 0 (all attached processes), since you can't depend on the process having been created as a new process group. After the spawned child exits, wait on the handle via `WaitForSingleObject` for a grace period, and if it times out, call `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: Note that `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, ...)` is not the same as the user typing Ctrl+C in the console window. It will not interrupt blocking console reads. If the main thread in the target process is blocked on `input()` or `sys.stdin.read()`, a `KeyBoardInterrupt` exception won't be raised until the user presses Enter or Ctrl+Z, Enter. Otherwise the same caveats apply, i.e. most blocking operations in Windows Python cannot be canceled with Ctrl+C, except some, such as `time.sleep`, that have been designed to wait on an event that the C signal handler sets.